# How to avoid the lexical error when input data to derby?

Tags: derby

I have some regular patterns values to be saved in derby. it includes a lot of delimited letter mentioned in the derby. How could I input this data to the derby?

```
insert into configuration_master (PROPERTY_ID,PROPERTY_KEY, PROPERTY_VALUE, PROPERTY_NAME , PROPERTY_DESCRIPTION , PROPERTY_VALIDATION  ,CATEGORY_1,CATEGORY_2,CATEGORY_3,FST_REG_DT,FNL_AMD_DT ) values( 'agent.dependency.urlpatterns','agent.dependency.urlpatterns',"
        \(\s*['"]#target['"]\s*\)\.attr\(\s*['"]action['"]\s*,['"]([\w]+\.do)['"]\)
        \.attr\(\s*['"]action['"]\s*\,\s*['"]([\w_/\?\=\&]+)['"]\s*\)
        a.href\s*\=\s*['"]([\w_/\?\=\&]+)['"]
        [\. ]action\s*\=\s*['"]([\w_/\?\=\&]+)['"]
        ['"]((/[\w\._]+)*/[\w\._]+\.do)['"]
        ['"]\S*\.html['"]
        (action|value|href)\s*=\s*['"]((\/[a-zA-Z0-9\$\{\}?=.]+){2,3})\/?['"]
        ",'agent.dependency.urlpatterns','','','DEFAULT','DEFAULT','DEFAULT','','')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to through that hideous regexp of yours and fix it all, but if you do want to insert it into your database, then:

- Use single quotes (`'`) to surround the entire regexp string.  At the moment you are using double quotes (`"`).
- Use two single quotes inside a string to represent a single-quote character within the string.  For example

  ```sql
   SELECT 'Don't do this' FROM some_table
  ```

  will fail with an error, but

  ```
   SELECT 'It''s better to do this' FROM some_table
  ```

  will select the string `It's better to do this`.

Comment: Or use a prepared statement with a substitution parameter, if you are writing a program to do this.

Comment: @BryanPendleton Exactly. You are right. I could solve my problem with that. Thanks!